# After creating my gatsby-node.js file with the pages properly instructed to be dynamically generated via graphql, I can't view any of detailed product

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

If I click on a certain product I get the following 404 error:
[image]

If I click on one of the first 6 products which guide me to the link listed within the screenshot above, i get an error regarding my qty being undefined as follows:
[image]

and when i close out of the error I am left with this:
[image]

AGAIN - I have included my gatsby-node.js as well as my QtyButton.js code below... I also have [linked to my github repo here with the most updated code](https://github.com/seanmodd/jamstack-frontend)...

**gatsby-node.js:**

```js
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Node APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
exports.createPages = async({
  graphql,
  actions
}) => {
  const {
    createPage
  } = actions

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        products: allStrapiProduct {
          edges {
            node {
              name
              strapiId
              description
              category {
                name
              }
              variants {
                id
                color
                size
                style
                price
                images {
                  localFile {
                    childImageSharp {
                      gatsbyImageData
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        categories: allStrapiCategory {
          edges {
            node {
              strapiId
              name
              description
              filterOptions {
                Size {
                  checked
                  label
                }
                Style {
                  checked
                  label
                }
                Color {
                  checked
                  label
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    throw result.errors
  }

  const products = result.data.products.edges
  const categories = result.data.categories.edges

  products.forEach(product => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${product.node.category.name.toLowerCase()}/${
        product.node.name.split(' ')[0]
      }`,
      component: require.resolve('./src/templates/ProductDetail.js'),
      context: {
        name: product.node.name,
        id: product.node.strapiId,
        category: product.node.category.name,
        description: product.node.description,
        variants: product.node.variants,
        product,
      },
    })
  })

  categories.forEach(category => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${category.node.name.toLowerCase()}`,
      component: require.resolve('./src/templates/ProductList.js'),
      context: {
        name: category.node.name,
        description: category.node.description,
        id: category.node.strapiId,
        filterOptions: category.node.filterOptions,
      },
    })
  })
}

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  loaders,
  actions
}) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/,
          use: loaders.null()
        }],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

**QtyButton.js**

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useContext
} from 'react'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup'
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge'
import {
  makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import {
  CartContext
} from '../../contexts'
import {
  addToCart,
  removeFromCart
} from '../../contexts/actions'

import Cart from '../../images/Cart'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  qtyText: {
    color: ({
      white
    }) => (white ? theme.palette.secondary.main : '#fff'),
  },
  mainGroup: {
    height: '3rem',
  },
  editButtons: {
    height: '1.525rem',
    borderRadius: 0,
    backgroundColor: ({
        white
      }) =>
      white ? '#fff' : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    borderLeft: ({
        white
      }) =>
      `2px solid ${white ? theme.palette.secondary.main : '#fff'}`,
    borderRight: ({
      round
    }) => (round ? 0 : '2px solid #fff'),
    borderBottom: 'none',
    borderTop: 'none',
    borderRadius: ({
      round
    }) => (round ? '0px 50px 50px 0px' : 0),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: ({
          white
        }) =>
        white ? '#fff' : theme.palette.secondary.light,
    },
  },
  endButtons: {
    backgroundColor: ({
        white
      }) =>
      white ? '#fff' : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    borderRadius: 50,
    border: 'none',
  },
  cartButton: {
    marginLeft: '0 !important',
    transition: 'background-color 1s ease',
  },
  minus: {
    marginTop: '-0.25rem',
  },
  minusButton: {
    borderTop: ({
        white
      }) =>
      `2px solid ${white ? theme.palette.secondary.main : '#fff'}`,
  },
  qtyButton: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: ({
          white
        }) =>
        white ? '#fff' : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
  },
  badge: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    padding: 0,
  },
  success: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.main,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.main,
    },
  },
}))

export default function QtyButton({
  stock,
  variants,
  selectedVariant,
  name,
  isCart,
  white,
  hideCartButton,
  round,
  override,
}) {
  const {
    cart,
    dispatchCart
  } = useContext(CartContext)
  const existingItem = isCart ?
    cart.find(item => item.variant === variants[selectedVariant]) :
    null
  const classes = useStyles({
    white,
    round
  })
  const [qty, setQtyState] = useState(isCart ? existingItem.qty : 1)
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)

  let setQty

  if (override) {
    setQty = val => {
      override.setValue(val)
      setQtyState(val)
    }
  } else {
    setQty = setQtyState
  }

  const handleChange = direction => {
    if (qty === stock[selectedVariant].qty && direction === 'up') {
      return null
    }

    if (qty === 1 && direction === 'down') {
      return null
    }

    const newQty = direction === 'up' ? qty + 1 : qty - 1

    setQty(newQty)

    if (isCart) {
      if (direction === 'up') {
        dispatchCart(addToCart(variants[selectedVariant], 1, name))
      } else if (direction === 'down') {
        dispatchCart(removeFromCart(variants[selectedVariant], 1))
      }
    }
  }

  const handleCart = () => {
    setSuccess(true)

    dispatchCart(
      addToCart(
        variants[selectedVariant],
        qty,
        name,
        stock[selectedVariant].qty
      )
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stock === null || stock === -1) {
      return undefined
    }
    if (qty === 0 && stock[selectedVariant].qty !== 0) {
      setQty(1)
    } else if (qty > stock[selectedVariant].qty) {
      setQty(stock[selectedVariant].qty)
    }
  }, [stock, selectedVariant])

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer

    if (success) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => setSuccess(false), 1500)
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [success])

  return ( <
    Grid item >
    <
    ButtonGroup classes = {
      {
        root: classes.mainGroup
      }
    } >
    <
    Button classes = {
      {
        root: clsx(classes.endButtons, classes.qtyButton)
      }
    } >
    <
    Typography variant = "h3"
    classes = {
      {
        root: classes.qtyText
      }
    } > {
      qty
    } <
    /Typography> <
    /Button> <
    ButtonGroup orientation = "vertical" >
    <
    Button onClick = {
      () => handleChange('up')
    }
    classes = {
      {
        root: classes.editButtons
      }
    } >
    <
    Typography variant = "h3"
    classes = {
      {
        root: classes.qtyText
      }
    } >
    +
    <
    /Typography> <
    /Button> <
    Button onClick = {
      () => handleChange('down')
    }
    classes = {
      {
        root: clsx(classes.editButtons, classes.minusButton)
      }
    } >
    <
    Typography variant = "h3"
    classes = {
      {
        root: clsx(classes.qtyText, classes.minus)
      }
    } >
    -
    <
    /Typography> <
    /Button> <
    /ButtonGroup> {
      hideCartButton ? null : ( <
        Button onClick = {
          handleCart
        }
        disabled = {
          stock ? stock[selectedVariant].qty === 0 : true
        }
        classes = {
          {
            root: clsx(classes.endButtons, classes.cartButton, {
              [classes.success]: success,
            }),
          }
        } >
        {
          success ? ( <
            Typography variant = "h3"
            classes = {
              {
                root: classes.qtyText
              }
            } > ✓
            <
            /Typography>
          ) : ( <
            Badge overlap = "circle"
            badgeContent = "+"
            classes = {
              {
                badge: classes.badge
              }
            } >
            <
            Cart color = "#fff" / >
            <
            /Badge>
          )
        } <
        /Button>
      )
    } <
    /ButtonGroup> <
    /Grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should have put some work into reading this site's rules, because your question violates them and thus will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to follow this code, you've pasted images rather than code blocks so it's extremely hard to know where each part belongs (even more if they are parts repeated between snapshots). Try to debug and add the interesting parts, not the whole file...

> and when i close out of the error I am left with this

Well, you should never close the issue. It needs to be fixed, not ignored.

Your `gatsby-node.js`, among querying a bunch of fields you are not using (image, price, etc) looks fair good. Remember that the `gatsby-node.js` is where you create pages and send data to your templates, just as is, don't query unnecessary fields to avoid long build times. You should query for those fields in your template query.

Said that regarding the "first issue", if your product page is not rendering, your problem is there. Run `gatsby clean` in each trial.

Regarding your blocking issue, the one is breaking your code, as I said, it's impossible to follow the trace given the details you've provided but I would try something like:

```
      <Button
        onClick={handleCart}
        disabled={stock[selectedVariant] ? stock[selectedVariant].qty === 0 : true}
        classes={{
          root: clsx(classes.endButtons, classes.cartButton, {
            [classes.success]: success,
          }),
        }}
      >
```

Clearly, in some of your products you don't have a `qty` property inside the `stock` object, that's why your code is breaking. You should pull the thread to know if that product should or shouldn't have `qty` and adapt the code logic to that business logic, not otherwise. The snippet above should fix your code-breaking issue but you need to know if your `Button` should or shouldn't have `qty` at that point.

If you are using optional chaining plugin you can simplify it as:

```
disabled={stock?.selectedVariant?.qty === 0 : true}
```